# Use only jQuery .click() event on nested leaf node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to be able to detect click events on the leaf node in a hierarchy.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span about="1">1
      <span about="2">2
        <span about="3">3</span>
        <span about="4">4</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use the following javascript:

```
$( "span" ).click(function(e) {
    var about = $(this).attr("about");
    console.log("clicked on "+about);
});
```

The problem is that if I click on '4', I get the following console output:

```
[Log] clicked on 4 
[Log] clicked on 2 
[Log] clicked on 1
```

So the event is called on `<span about="4">` but also on its parents. But I only want the event being called on `<span about="4">` so that I can change the background colour of this span element.

How can I prevent the event being called on its parents?

Comment: but if you click on `2`?

Comment: call `e.stopPropagation();` and it should do it.